compare machine catalog images of a citrix machine
I am trying to compare each ProdImage of ProdMasterImages with UATImage of UATMasterImages and if the image name matches i have to get the respective ProdCatalogNames of that ProdMasterImage.
Below is the code
$ProdMasterImages = foreach($ProdCatalog in $ProdCatalogs) {
    $GetMasterProd = (Get-BrokerCatalog -Name $ProdCatalog).ProvisioningSchemeId.guid
    $ImagePathProd = Get-Provscheme -provisioningSchemeUid $GetMasterProd | select MasterImageVM
    $ProdImage = (Split-Path -Path $ImagePathProd -Leaf).Replace("}", "")
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ProdCatalogName = $ProdCatalog
        ProdImage       = $ProdImage
    }
}
Write-Output $ProdMasterImages
    
$UATMasterImages = foreach ($UATCatalog in $UATCatalogs) {
    $GetMasterUAT = (Get-BrokerCatalog -Name $UATCatalog).ProvisioningSchemeId.guid
    $ImagePathUAT = Get-Provscheme -provisioningSchemeUid $GetMasterUAT | select MasterImageVM
    $UATImage = (Split-Path -Path $ImagePathUAT -Leaf).Replace("}", "")
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        UATCatalogName = $UATCatalog
        UATImage       = $UATImage
    }
}
Write-Output $UATMasterImages
    
foreach ($ProdMasterImage in $ProdMasterImages.PSObject.Properties) {
    foreach ($UATMasterImage in $UATMasterImages.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($ProdMasterImage.ProdImage -eq $UATMasterImage.UATImage) {
            $ProdCalaogName = $ProdMasterImage.Name
            Write-Output $ProdCalaogName
        }
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the first part, you assign the catalog name associated with each production image to a property named ProdCatalogName:
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ProdCatalogName = $ProdCatalog
        ProdImage       = $ProdImage
    }

But then in the last loop, you reference a property named Name instead:
        if ($ProdMasterImage.ProdImage -eq $UATMasterImage.UATImage) {
            $ProdCalaogName = $ProdMasterImage.Name   # 'Name' -ne 'ProdCatalogName'
            Write-Output $ProdCalaogName
        }

Change the property name and it'll work:
        if ($ProdMasterImage.ProdImage -eq $UATMasterImage.UATImage) {
            $ProdCatalogName = $ProdMasterImage.ProdCatalogName
            Write-Output $ProdCatalogName
        }


Thank you for the response. I have tried it, the issue I am facing is - I am not even able to compare the images itself. '$ProdMasterImage.ProdImage -eq $UATMasterImage.UATImage' is not retrieving ProdImage of that particular object

@SaiMounikaChintala Change foreach ($ProdMasterImage in $ProdMasterImages.PSObject.Properties) to foreach ($ProdMasterImage in $ProdMasterImages) (same with the inner loop)
